# Is it possible for a pine tree to grow in your lungs?

Tags: plants, anatomy

This question came up at lunch today, and I didn't believe my friend when he said someone had a pine tree growing in his lungs.

I have found several sources: [1](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1169861/Shocked-Russian-surgeons-open-man-thought-tumour--FIR-TREE-inside-lung.html), [2](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/russia/5152953/Surgeons-find-fir-tree-growing-inside-patients-lung.html), [3](http://www.foxnews.com/story/0,2933,514955,00.html)

Source #2 has a key note:

> There was no independent verification of the surgeon's claims.

Other sources state that it was green, which is hard for me to believe. How could a plant grow with no light inside a lung? Is this actually possible, or just a news report that has been widely circulated?

Comment: Growing probably not, but germination certainly.

Comment: Could also be descended from this: in 1995 a 16 year old girl had a piece of christmas tree removed from her lungs, she had accidentally breathed it in when she was a baby.   https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1995-12-16-mn-14617-story.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a well known urban legend.

This letter published on Chest Journal addresses the issue

[Trees Don't Grow in the Lungs!](http://journal.publications.chestnet.org/article.aspx?articleid=1090121) - Chua and Mehta, 2009

> We would like to bring to the attention of readers that trees do not grow in humans. To the best of our knowledge, there has never been a single report in the medical literature of seeds and/or plants growing in humans. If they did, watermelon seeds and peanuts,<sup>4,5</sup> which are the most commonly aspirated foreign bodies, would be growing out of control from our lungs. Moreover, it makes no biological sense that in the absence of sunlight and appropriate nutrient medium, photosynthesis and germination of a seed can take place.
>
> <sup>4</sup> - Mahafza  T, Khader  Y;  [Aspirated tracheobronchial foreign bodies: a Jordanian experience](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17385621), Ear Nose Throat J 2007
>
> <sup>5</sup> Chik  KK, Miu  TY, Chan  CW;  [Foreign body aspiration in Hong Kong Chinese children](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19197090), Hong Kong Med J 2009 [PubMed]

Comment: "it makes no biological sense" is a statement, not proof (not that I disagree with it, but proof it doesn't make).

Comment: How about this? http://abcnews.go.com/blogs/headlines/2010/08/pea-sprout-removed-from-massachusetts-mans-lung/ And the last statement in the quote makes no sense at all. Seeds bring all their nutrients with them to sprout. They certainly do not need sunlight(seeds sprout below the ground) and they do not need nutrients other then water. And air humidity is often enough for that (which you have plenty in your lungs)

Comment: Also explained here http://healthland.time.com/2010/08/13/how-can-a-pea-plant-grow-in-the-lung/

Comment: @DVK: I think the requirements for a plant to grow are very well explained in any biology textbook. A twig without roots cannot grow in someone's lung.

Comment: Starting seeds are often done in the dark, and moved to sunlight after they start growing. They need water and not much else.

Comment: @decker: sure but guess what? They develop roots, they do not grow directly as twigs...

Comment: I'm not saying that people have trees growing in their lungs, just commenting on the absence of sunlight point in the post.

Comment: @decker: well, but the claim is that the surgeon found a pine twig in the patient's lung...

Comment: @Stefan: your second link only supports the explanation that the story is made up, as the plant magically becomes a pea sprout, when the images clearly show a fairly developed pine twig.

Comment: Seeds are grown under layers of dirt frequently, they are capable of growing without light provided they get the rest of the nutrients, just not very well, nor for very long.

Comment: This answer in no way answers the question "Is it possible?". The answer is simply conjecture, additionally, its false. Photosynthesis is not required for germination and how do we know there is not a nutrient medium? I'm not saying that it is possible to grow a tree in a lung, but this answer doesn't show that it isn't. "To the best of our knowledge there has never been a single report"? So what? To the best of my knowledge there has never been a single report, but that's because I haven't looked. It proves nothing.

Comment: @Randy: the answer just says that there is no evidence for it to happen. That does not mean it can happen, it means that **to the best of our current knowledge** it does not. Because swallowing seeds is fairly common, if germination were indeed to happen, finding seedlings of plants in lungs should be very common. The fact that not a single reports exist, makes it very unlikely that the phenomenon really happen. Furthermore the quote does not say that germination requires photosynthesis. It includes photosynthesis because the original report does not show a seedling but a growing tree(!)

Comment: @Randy: (cont'd) On top of that, the photos clearly show a green/brownish twig, which clearly requires photosynthesis. In summary, Occam's razor would say this is just a hoax.

Comment: The question is "Is it **possible** for a pine tree to grow in your lungs?".  Did you answer the question?  In my opinion, no.

Comment: Furthermore, I often see seeds sprouting and growing **inside** cucumbers. Here is a pic of pumpkin seeds growing inside a pumpkin which looks eerily like a lung http://sharedharvestcsa.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/cheese-pumpkin.jpg  Looks like germination has taken place to me.

Comment: @Randy: please look at the (obviously fake) photos of the lung. It is not a sprout you see there, it's a twig... We do not have sufficient data to answer the question so I answered as good as possible. If you have better evidence you are extremely welcome to write your own answer.

Answer (score 10):

The show 'Monster Inside Me' actually has documentation of an older man with respitory problems who did asperate a raw pea and it did germinate and start to grow inside his lung.  It was removed on the 3rd Bronchisotomy trying to get a biopsy.   All germination requires is moisture, warmth and oxygen.  Any seed could do this, although it would not get very big before blocking off and collapsing the lung.
[Discovery Blog (Internet Archive)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130317021857/http://blogs.discovery.com/bites-animal-planet/2012/11/watch-attack-of-the-killer-peas.html)

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Monsters_Inside_Me_episodes#Season_3_(2012)), the episode in question is S3E6, "A Monster's Taking My Baby".