# Did a tree grow inside a man's lung after he inhaled a seed?

Tags: biology

https://www.newshub.co.nz/world/fir-tree-in-lung-surgeon-stands-by-his-story-2009041623

> The Russian surgeon who says he found a fir tree growing inside a patient’s lungs is standing by a claim that has been met with wide disbelief in the medical world.
>
> The surgeon, Vladimir Kamashev, said he was "shocked" to find a five
> centimetre branch while operating on a patient in the central city of
> Izhevsk. He said he initially thought the branch was a tumour, and
> suggested the patient could have inhaled a seed during his military
> service in Siberia that then sprouted.
>
> But Dr Stephen Spiro, vice chairman of the British Lung Foundation,
> said that would be "pretty near impossible."
>
> Graeme Berlyn, a professor of tree anatomy at Yale University, said a
> fir seed could not germinate in the lung because it needs sunlight.
>
> Sky News / AP

This case was covered by ABC news, as well. https://abcnews.go.com/Health/photos/photos-medical-marvels-2024849/image-7351759

All sources on this are making the same claim - that the man must've inhaled a seed or bud, and the 5-cm long fir tree then grew inside of his lung.

This is a photo of the tree once it was extracted from the lung:

[image]

There doesn't seem to be any roots there.  Snopes doesn't have an article on this.

**Did this 5-cm long 'tree' really grow inside this man's lung?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible for a pine tree to grow in your lungs?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15373/is-it-possible-for-a-pine-tree-to-grow-in-your-lungs). I know how disappointing it can be to do your research, write a great question, then realise you should have checked for duplicates here too.